# Extracting filter coefficients from fdatool IIR filter object

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have designed an IRR filter in fdatool but since I can't export the coefficients as a vector into the workspace, I exported the filter as an object. The problem is that when I open the object, I have 3 arrays stored in it (ScaleValues, States, and sosMatrix). Please, could someone explain to me the difference between each array and, more importantly, how I can extract the filter coefficients from my IRR filter? Also if you could write down links to official sources/documentation, it would amazing. Please, any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I am converting my structure to Direct-Form 1since, supposedly, it gives the coefficients for the ideal IRR filter or is, at least, more accurate but I am also not sure about it and if someone could also explain to me what it is exactly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I am using a Lowpass Chebyshev Type II filter for my IIR. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values of coeffiecient use following method on structure

```
Hd.coefficients
```

To read individual Matrix values

```
Hd.States
Hd.ScaleValues
Hd.sosMatrix
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem is knowing which are the actual coefficients. The ones used for analysing the filter.

Comment: The sosMatrix (second order sections) are holding the coefficients, however, you should read about sos to really understand how to interpret them [e.g. here](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Series_Second_Order_Sections.html)